# Not adding the customers total correctly

Tags: java, arrays

So when I run this it does not add the customer total all together. It just keeps displaying the last item entered as the customer total.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dinerBill {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    double taxRate = 0, customerTotal=0, discountType = 0, grandTotal= 0;


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] itemName = { "0) Soup", "1) Wing", "2) Burger", "3) Chicken Sandwich", "4) Fries", "5) Pie", "6) Ice Cream", "7) Soft drink", "8) Coffee"};
    double [] itemPrice= {2.50 , .15 , 4.95, 5.95, 1.99, 2.95, 2.99, 1.50, 1.00};

    System.out.println("Enter the number of people in the party");
    int numberOfPeople  = in.nextInt();

    while (numberOfPeople >0) {

    System.out.println("Enter 1 if customer recieves teen or eldery discount ");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 if the customer recieves no discount");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 if the customer is under 5");
    discountType = in.nextInt();

    if (discountType == 1) {
        discountType = .85;
         taxRate = 1;
    }
    if (discountType ==2) {
        discountType = 1;
        taxRate = 1.05;
    }
    if (discountType ==3)
        discountType = 0;



    System.out.printf("%-24s", "Menu");
    System.out.print("Prices" + "\n");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < itemName.length; i++) {

    System.out.printf("%-24.21s" ,itemName[i]);
    System.out.print(itemPrice[i] +"\n");

    }
    System.out.println("Enter the corresponding number");
    for (int choices=3; choices > 0; choices--) {
        double choicePrice = 0 , customerTotalBeforeDiscount = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter customers item");
        int customerItem = in.nextInt();

        if (customerItem ==1) {
        System.out.println("How many wings ordered?");
        int wingsOrdered = in.nextInt();
        double priceOfWings = wingsOrdered * itemPrice[1];
        choicePrice = priceOfWings;}
        else
            choicePrice = itemPrice[customerItem];

        customerTotalBeforeDiscount +=choicePrice;
        double customerTotalBeforeTax = customerTotalBeforeDiscount * discountType;
        customerTotal = customerTotalBeforeTax * taxRate;
    }

    System.out.print("The total for the customer is $" );
    System.out.printf("%.2f \n" , customerTotal );

    grandTotal += customerTotal;


    numberOfPeople--;
    }

    System.out.print("The total is $");
    System.out.printf("%.2f", grandTotal);

    in.close();

    System.exit(0);
    }

 }
```

Here are the results that I'm getting:

> *Enter the number of people in the party*

1

> *Enter 1 if customer recieves teen or eldery discount*
>
> *Enter 2 if the customer recieves no discount*
>
> *Enter 3 if the customer is under 5*

2

```
Menu                    Prices
--------------------------------
0) Soup                 2.5
1) Wing                 0.15
2) Burger               4.95
3) Chicken Sandwich     5.95
4) Fries                1.99
5) Pie                  2.95
6) Ice Cream            2.99
7) Soft drink           1.5
8) Coffee               1.0
```

> *Enter the corresponding number*
>
> *Enter customers item*

0

> *Enter customers item*

0

> *Enter customers item*

0

> *The total for the customer is $2.6*3
>
> *The total is $2.63*

Comment: Why is `choices` fixed to 3? Wouldn't it make sense to make it more flexible?

Comment: yes it would, but the assignment states that everyone orders exactly 3 items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
double choicePrice = 0 , customerTotalBeforeDiscount = 0;
```

because it resets customerTotalBeforeDiscount on each iteration. Instead do:

```
double customerTotalBeforeDiscount = 0;
for (int choices=3; choices > 0; choices--) {
    double choicePrice = 0;
```

Comment: after making those changes, im still getting the same answer.

Comment: I tried it with 2 persons and soup, it worked. Are you sure you put  `customerTotalBeforeDiscount = 0` outside of the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

well after looking at it , the customer total did reset to 0, after I fixed that, I noticed that it was =+ and not +=.

```
 customerTotalBeforeDiscount =+ choicePrice;
 customerTotalBeforeDiscount += choicePrice;
```

so yes yours was right but somehow I got the += changed when it was correct in my original post.